# Java Console-Based Application on remote server

Tags: java

I have a Java Application,which performs ocr on images(uses tesseract, OpenCV library aswell).this image will be sent to this application through an android app.i want to upload this application to remote server.is there any way to run this application on server like a php script that keeps running on a server on multiple requests.

i have looked for glassfish server for deployment of java Applications.is this the right approach?
will this work for my specific need as i have to provide an image each time i make request to this application on remote server.or is there another approach to this problem.

Comment: Well glassfish might be a bit overkill. You can use tomcat and for example RESTEasy.

Comment: you could use Glassfish. For simplicity I'd use Tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before talking about application servers like Glassfish, you first need to understand how Java works on the web. There are plenty of ways and frameworks to do it and the simplest is to work with Java Servlets.

You can start with the [oficial Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html) and [stack overflow's wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) about Java Servlets and then choose an application server (Glassfish, JBoss, Websphere, etc.) or a servlet container (like Tomcat, which I would recommend) to publish your java web application to.